# `\mathcal` incompatible with `unicode-math`

Tags: unicode-math, mathcal

An MWE is like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
$ \tilde{\mathcal{B}} $

% $ \hat{\mathcal{B}} $
\end{document}
```

The error shows "! Internal error: bad native font flag in `map_char_to_glyph'".

It seems that `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}` is not compatible with `unicode-math`. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re trying to load an old-fashioned NFSS font command, which is incompatible with `unicode-math`.

To load a new `\mathcal` alphabet from an OpenType font, use the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`, for example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}[
  Scale = MatchUppercase ]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[
  range = {cal,bfcal},
  Scale = MatchUppercase ]

\begin{document}
\[ \mathcal{ABC} \quad \mathscr{ABC} \]
\end{document}
```

This loads both the `\mathcal` and `\mathbfcal` alphabets, and scales the fonts so that their capital letters are the same height.

Comment: Thanks very much!